# can not read property of undefined angular 6 *ngIf issue

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application .html file I have code as below

```
<div *ngIf="checkForStatus()" class="row">
         .......
</div>
```

and in .ts File, I have code as below:

```
    @Input() values: OrderResponse;
    checkForStatus() {
      this.values.signers.forEach((ele)=>{
      ...................  
       return ....something.
     }
}
```

Here I am getting value from the ts file's function in HTML but there are console errors saying that **can not read property signers of **undefined**.**

therefor I change the logic of the template as below:

```
<div *ngIf="values.signers">
<div *ngIf="checkForStatus()" class="row">
             .......
    </div>
</div>
```

just wrapped the code with div with *ngIf, this works well? but is it a appropriate situation? am I missing something here? may be bad practices ?

Please note that I am using @Input **values** directly into html file.

Comment: Can you console the `values` and see what is inside ?

Comment: it is returning vaues, that is not an issue, my gut feeling says template is getting render before ts code finishes.

Comment: On `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook check the `@Input` value whether it is assigned at the initial load or it takes time ? If it takes time add a condition there and create a variable in your ts. Use the same in your `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **values** property is undefined. In template you could prevent that error in that way:

```html
<div *ngIf="values?.signers"></div>
```

In component class:

```js
checkForStatus() {
  if(this.values) {
    // here values property is defined
  }
}
```

Comment: Marek, I already did this trick, as you can see in my code when I use <div *ngIf=values.signers"> it does solve that error, and but it does not help if I do same thing in ts file as you mentioned.

Comment: @user12925068, You've also added **if** statement to method?

Comment: So, in which specific place in your code you're gettting this error?

Comment: it works well, but in console I get error in console of undefined

Comment: "error in console of undefined" - but in which line? and which file? ts? html?

Comment: in html file, it does what it suppose to do, but because of asynchronous behavior it could not get loaded at first time.

Comment: Did you use optional chaining operator in template (html file)? **values?.signers** - this should prevent this error, like I've written in my answer

Comment: Ok, could you update your question with whole ts and html files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `this.values` is not set in all situations. So when you take a look at your code, when do you initialize `this.values` ?

I would assume that it is currently filled asynchronously (that means the parent could not provide the value at creation time). As a result, when the component is created, the first rendering will happen before `this.values` is filled. Then, a few milliseconds later, the value gets assigned.
Because of that the second solution works and the first not. In the first it explodes, because at the first rendering, the value is not available.

Therfor you have multiple ways to handle the problem.
You can try to fight the symptom and make a check if the necessary value is available and if not then return a acceptable value

```
checkForStatus() {
  if(!this.values){
    return false;
  }
this.values.signers.forEach((ele)=>{
  ...................  
   return ....something.
}
```

Or you could analyze the source of the problem and check if the asynchronously nature is necessary.

For example the parent could only add the child component into the DOM when every value is available.

```
<childComponent [values]="this.values" *ngIf="this.values"></childComponent>
```

The solution is very depending on what you want to achieve and how the look and feel should be.

Answer (score 0):

It is because input properties are populated before `ngOnInit()` is called. When you are accessing it using `*ngIf` it still `undefined`. So, you might assign a value to the property while declaring it:

```
@Input() values: OrderResponse = {};
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on this little ?

Comment: when I did like above it says Type 'undefined[]' has no properties in common with type 'OrderResponse '

Comment: this seems to be working... I tried like this.. @Input() values: OrderResponse = {};

Comment: When you declare "values" without assigning any value to it, it automatically evaluates to undefined. Then when you try to access the "values" variable in *ngIf="checkForStatus()", its value hasn't been assigned to it yet as input property. That's  why you get it equals to undefined. But when you give it anything even if it's an empty object it works fine because it has a value now.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Omar Mohamed suggested, but I used `{}` instead.

```
@Input() values: OrderResponse = {};
```

Comment: I believe it's not the best solution, because it suggest that **values** input is optional. I don't think you want to achieve this.